# Azure Durable Function getting slower and slower over time

Tags: azure-durable-functions

My Azure Durable Function(Runtime V3) getting an average of 3M events per day. When it runs for two or three weeks it is getting slower and slower. When I remove two table storages(History & Instances) used by Durable Function Framework, it is getting better and works as expected. I hosted my function app in the consumption plan. And also inside my function app, **I'm used Durabel Entities as well.** In my code, I'm using sub orchestrators as well for the Fan-Out mechanism.

Is this problem possible when it comes to heavy workload? Do I need to clear those table storages from time to time or do I need to Delete the state of completed entities inside my Durable Entity Function?

Someone, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should perform periodic clean-ups yourself by calling the [PurgeInstanceHistoryAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#purge-instance-history) method. See a similar post on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894392

Answer (score 1):

Also review any loops or [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#monitoring) patterns that you may have in your code.
Any looping logic, (like `foreach`, `for` or `while` loops) will replay from the initial startup state. Whilst the Durable Function replay architecture is very efficient at doing this, the code we write may not be optimised for repetitive iterations.

> [Durable Monitor Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#monitoring) is *almost* an Anti-Pattern. The concept is OK but it is easily misinterpreted and is open to abuse. It is designed for a low-frequency loop that polls an endpoint either for a set number of iterations or up until a finite time, or of course when the state of the endpoint being monitoried has changed. That state change will be the trigger to perform the rest of the operation.
>
> It is **NOT** an example of how to use general or high frequency looping structures in Durable functions
>
> It is **NOT** and example of how to implement a traditional HTTP endpoint reporting monitor in an infinite loop (`while(true)`) style, perhaps to record changes into a data store over time.

If your durable function logic has an iterator that may involve many iterations, consider migrating the iteration step to a sub-orchestration that uses the [Eternal Orchestration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations) pattern